# why am I getting "column count doesnt match value count at row 1"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, c#-4.0, database-connection

I have created a registration page in aspx and i need the values entered in that page to be appended in the mysql database on button click. the database has 4  columns only
this is my code:

```
protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=register;User=root;Password=palomi@2000");
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO register VALUES (@fn,@ln,@em,@pw)", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", TextBox5.Text.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", TextBox2.Text.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", TextBox3.Text.ToString());
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Login_page.aspx");
}
```

but im getting "column doesnt match value" error

Comment: What's the structure of the table?

Comment: Please always post the FULL - COMPLETE Error message, not a summary, and preferably not as the title of your question

Answer (score 1):

You are passing four values in your `VALUES` clause. If the table has more columns or fewer columns, then these four values won't match the set of columns.

So how is SQL supposed to know which values you want in which columns?

You can fix it by specifying the columns:

```
"INSERT INTO register (col1, col2, col5, col6) VALUES (@fn,@ln,@em,@pw)"
```

This syntax of `INSERT` means that col1 will be assigned the value of @fn, and likewise for each other column.

Columns that are not named in your `INSERT` will be assigned their `DEFAULT` value defined in the table, or else NULL if there is no default.

MySQL also has an alternative syntax for `INSERT` that makes it easier:

```
INSERT INTO register SET col1=@fn, col2=@ln, col5=@em, col6=@pw
```

This isn't standard syntax, so don't use it on other brands of SQL database. But it's convenient because it's easy to see exactly which value is matched with each column.